# Error Code: 1289. The 'SHOW PROCEDURE|FUNCTION CODE' feature is disabled; to have it working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, alter

i want to show my procedure code from mysql workbench program. i right click on any procedure and click the "alter procedure" option but didn't happen anything.

and i'm try another way to show my code and alter the procedure's codes. with mysql code i want to show to the codes, this code statement follow:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE CODE pusers
```

but i getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1289. The 'SHOW PROCEDURE|FUNCTION CODE' feature is disabled;  to have it working
```

My OS is MAC Lion OSX and MySQL Workbench program version are "version 5.2.47 revision 10398" and "version 5.2.45  revision 10251". There are old and new versions of this program.

have u got any idea?

Comment: with what user you created the procedure? and with what user you tried to exec `SHOW PROCEDURE`? my guess is that they are 2 different users

Answer (score 3):

It's by design.

> **[SHOW PROCEDURE CODE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-procedure-code.html)**
>   This statement is a MySQL extension that is available **only for servers that
>   have been built with debugging support**. It displays a representation
>   of the internal implementation of the named stored procedure.

As the error message explicitly says if you want to be able to use this feature you need to build your MySql with `--with-debug` option.